# Kill Chrome Browser process

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome

in order to kill a process, I usually use

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("process name")(0).Kill()
```

This does not work if I want to close Chrome, using "Chrome" as the process name.
I know that Google Chrome runs with more than one process, at least that's what my task manager shows, so I guess this is the problem: because there are several processes called "Chrome", vb.net is unable to close them all or just closes one which doesn't lead to Chrome closing.

What code could I use instead, to close ALL processes called "Chrome"?

Comment: How about a loop?

Comment: BTW: closing is usually cooperative, whereas killing is not. Your title says something different than your description.

Comment: @UweKeim But how can I know how often my loop has to run? How can I know  how many processes of Chrome are running?

Comment: `Process.GetProcessesByName("process name")` returns all the processes named "Chrome"; just iterate through the collection

Comment: You can also filter the result of `Process.GetProcessesByName()`, adding a `.Where()/.Any()` clause, to only return a Process when the `Process.MainWindowHandle IsNot IntPtr.zero`. Then repeat the check for all processes (one/some may be get stuck).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
Dim i As Integer = Ubound(Process.GetProcessesByName("Chrome.exe"))
For x As Integer = i To 0 Step -1
    Process.GetProcessesByName("Chrome.exe")(x) .Kill()
Next
```

Comment: Please use a `For Each` loop instead or at least store the array in a variable. That code will iterate all processes for every iteration of your loop, meaning if your PC is running 200 processes and 10 of them are Chrome, your code will perform 2200 iterations instead of just 210.